# regex for everything

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

i am trying a regex to extract the content between `!` and `|thumbnail!`.

I am using `[^&]*(!)[^&]*(|thumbnail!)[^&]*` to get the content. My pattern is:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^&]*(!)[^&]*(|thumbnail!)[^&]*)",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

The text can contain any characters including returns, newline and so on. Please assist how I can extract the content. Thanks

Comment: Use `"(?s)!(.*?)\\|thumbnail!"` (or if you have `&`-delimited string, replace `.` with `[^&]`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried this pattern for this string, it didnt work:                    <br>
<br> !Silhouette analysis.png|thumbnail! 
<br>. could you please help?

Comment: First of all, [it works](https://regex101.com/r/gequrd/1). Second, see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).